# How to fix Sylius Installation Error for timezone?

Tags: sylius

I'm running

```
php bin/console sylius:install
```

from the command line, but getting an exception:
[image: timezone error. recommendation is blank]

Upon first getting this, I updated my php.ini date.timezone to America/New_York and restarted Apache. The date.timezone in phpinfo() output now shows America/New_York for both local and master values (they were blank prior to this). But the Sylius installation error remains.

Is there some sort of cache I need to clear before it will work? Or do you have other ideas of the cause?

Answer (score 4):

OS: **Ubuntu**

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/php/version/cli/php.ini
```

find **date.timezone**, if commented, uncomment the line and set value as **"America/Los_Angeles"**

try installing sylius it will work.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/9251

The timezone must (also?) be set in php.ini for cli scripts.